# Putting two R maps() side by side

Tags: r, graphics, maps

Is it possible to get these two maps side by side, *with the same height,* in one png image? The two images should be separated by minimal but appropriate space, as shown below. I am receptive to other solutions, especially `ggmap.`

I tried `par(mar=...` (and also `mai`) to reduce margin size but that did not seem to affect size or space between the two maps. I also used `cex = 1.8` in the second par() function (for the state) which makes the height of the two maps similar but spaces them even farther apart.

When I save the file as PDF, I get each map on a separate page. When I try png, I get only the Missouri map.

**MWE:**

```
library(maps)

op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
png(file = "maps.png", width = 1000, height = 400)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('state')
map('state', 'missouri', add = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
map('state', c('mississippi', 'alabama', 'north carolina', 'florida'), add = TRUE, fill = TRUE, col = "gray")

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('county', 'missouri')
map('county', 'missouri,scott', add=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

dev.off()

par(op)
```

**Desired result:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried ggplot2::geom_sf() and patchwork library? i. e. p1 + p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `par` options are specific to the active "graphic device" at that moment. To demonstrate:

Try this, starting with "normal" (non-file) graphics.

```
par(mfrow=1:2)
par('mfrow')
# [1] 1 2
png("maps.png")
par('mfrow')
# [1] 1 1
dev.off()
# windows 
#       2 
par('mfrow')
# [1] 1 2
```

I didn't close the previous plain-graphics-window, so once I closed the `png` device, the previously-active window became active again. And it was still thinking `mfrow=1:2`.

So I think your answer is this, where the only change is the order of `png`, `par(mfrow=1:2)`.

```
png(file = "maps.png", width = 1000, height = 400)
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('state')
map('state', 'missouri', add = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
map('state', c('mississippi', 'alabama', 'north carolina', 'florida'), add = TRUE, fill = TRUE, col = "gray")

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('county', 'missouri')
map('county', 'missouri,scott', add=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

dev.off()

par(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Andres comment, I developed a `ggplot2` version that places the two maps side by side using `patchwork.` I found it easier for me to use `geom_polygon` instead of converting the maps to `sf` objects.

```
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes) # for Tufte theme
library(patchwork)

# remove the unneeded ink not removed by
# theme_tufte()
theme_tufte_empty <- function(){
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "cm"))
}

usa <- map_data("state")
us_missouri <- map_data('state','missouri') #do similar for other states

us_map <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = usa, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = NA, color = "black") + 
  geom_polygon(data = us_missouri, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "black") +
  theme_tufte() + # quickly remove most ink
  theme_tufte_empty() +  
  coord_fixed(1.3)

missouri <- map_data("county", "missouri")
mo_scott <- map_data("county", "missouri,scott")

mo_map <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = missouri, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = NA, color = "black") + 
  geom_polygon(data = mo_scott, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "black") +
  theme_tufte() +
  theme_tufte_empty() +
  coord_fixed(1.3)

us_map + mo_map + plot_layout(ncol = 2, widths = c(1.5,1))
```

[image]